# Drupal 7 - Newsletter 7.x-1.0-beta9

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed newsletter module in Drupal 7 
I can not active module please help me.

Requires: 
Entityreference (missing),
Token (missing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and enable [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module and [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module.